# Perlcritic: How can I resolve '^Magic variable "$ENV" should be assigned as "local"'?

Tags: perl, environment-variables, perl-critic

I am writing a perl script that needs to set a number of environment variables before calling an external program. My code has the form

```
$ENV{'VAR1'}    = "value1";
$ENV{'VAR2'}    = "value2";
```

When running this through perlcritic, I get a severity 4 violation for every such assignement:

```
^Magic variable "$ENV" should be assigned as "local"
```

Googling that error message didn't give me any good solutions. The perlcritic violation that complains in that case is Variables::RequireLocalizedPunctuationVars, and the example given deals with localizing a file handle. I tried to find the relevant section in Perl Best Practices, but it only talks about localizing package variables.

One solution I tried is to localize %ENV using the following statement before the assignments.

```
local %ENV = ();
```

This doesn't resolve the violation.

My question is the following:

Is that Perlcritic violation even relevant for assignments to %ENV, or can I ignore it?

If it's relevant, what's the best way to resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perlcritic warnings are not The Word of God.  They are simply warnings about situations that, if managed incorrectly, could get you into trouble.

> Is that Perlcritic violation even relevant for assignments to %ENV, or
>   can I ignore it?

This warning tells you that:

1. Global Variables have the very real possibility of action at a distance.
2. This possibility is even more dangerous when dealing with those variables that change the operation of built in functions.

Is that relevant for `%ENV`?  If you spawn more than one child process in your program, Yes.  If someone changes your program later to spawn another child,  Yes.

> If it's relevant, what's the best way to resolve it?

Now here is where being the human being becomes important.  You need to make a value judgement.

Possible actions:

- Ignore the warning and hope that future maintainers aren't bitten by your usage of this Global Variable.
- Change your code to avoid the situation you are being warned about.  The syntax suggested by choroba is a fine option.

Now if you have made a change, are still getting the warning, and believe that the warning is now in error, you can do one or more of:

- Be a good citizen and [Submit a bug report.](https://github.com/Perl-Critic/Perl-Critic/issues)
- use the comment `## no critic (RequireLocalizedPunctuationVars)` on the affected lines or on it's own line before the lines in question.
- Or more excessively disable the rule or just create an exception for `%ENV` in your `.perlcriticrc` file.

Answer (score 6):

You can localize the value for the given environment variable only:

```
local $ENV{VAR1} = 'value1';
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Env](http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html).  `perlcritic` does not complain about the variable:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Env qw(VAR);

$VAR = "value1";
```